# How to integrate a failover WS without client reconfiguration?

Tags: iis, cluster, failovercluster

I have a web service hosted by IIS server 1 and another web service hosted by IIS server 2.

Is there a way to have the WS on server 2 automatically pick up when the WS on server 1 is unavailable, without having to reconfigure the clients (which are desktop applications in this case).

There must be some tools that perform such tasks, please help.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
The two web services expose the same functionality, so basically I am trying to setup a **high-availability cluster** (ie **failover cluster**)

Comment: dns failover or IP failover are the solutions

Answer (score 2):

MSCS failover might work here - see http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2009/10/27/iis7-and-failover-clustering.aspx for a discussion and links about IIS 7 and MSCS failover.

The only real alternative is to find a load balancer. For the client not to be interrupted implies a virtual IP is required, and some interruption may be inevitable in any case (a TCP reconnection might be required).

If the two web services *are the same* i.e. are 100% interchangeable, consider an NLB cluster, or a reverse proxy cluster that can perform health monitoring. (NLB doesn't do health monitoring; NLB doesn't care).

On the Microsoft side, TMG or ISA Server could do this, with health monitoring, and clustering built in. Application Request Routing for IIS 7 could also perform this failover and health monitoring role, but you'd need to manually cluster the ARR boxes.